# Isotope wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am currently working on a website in wordpress using the IKROS template. I have reached a point that is outside my understanding.
What I would like help getting to work is implementing JQUERY BBQ to the ISOTOPE. The end product would be a linkable categories from other pages that bring you to the filtered category page.. I think what is just throwing me off is the php.
I just can seem to integrate JQUERY BBQ into my wordpress.
Has anybody had any success in this field?

```
<code><div id="portfolio">


        <ul class="filter">
        <li><a class="active" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
        <?php 
        $portfolio_categories = get_categories(array('taxonomy'=>'portfolio_category'));
        foreach($portfolio_categories as $portfolio_category)
            echo '<li><a href="#" data-filter=".' . $portfolio_category->slug . '">' . $portfolio_category->name . '</a></li>';
        ?>
    </ul></code>
```

This is the line in the portfolio template that produces the link to the categories.
Thank's for any help in advance!

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Is it erroring? If so, provide the error.

Comment: Its not really erroring, it's just not adding the hash history state. I want to be able to do this in the end http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/hash-history.html but I a not clear on how to add it to my Wordpress code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the html of your list and apply his jQuery, [do view source to see his html and his jQuery](http://view-source:http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/tests/combo-sort-history.html)